# Filtering Nodes based on its text()

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the below XML

```
<Categories>
<cat>Video</cat>
<cat>Audio</cat>
<cat>Hybrid</cat>
</Categories>
```

In my XSL, I would like to filter 'Audio' and pass the rest of nodes to a calling template which takes nodes as one of the parameter. How to achieve this.

I tried the below, but no luck.

attempt 1:

```
<xsl:call-template name='xx'>
<xsl:with-param name='nodes' select="/Categories/cat[text()='Hybrid' or 'Video']"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

attempt 2:

```
<xsl:call-template name='xx'>
<xsl:with-param name='nodes' select="/Categories/cat[text()='Hybrid' or text()='Video']"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

attempt 3:

```
<xsl:call-template name='xx'>
<xsl:with-param name='nodes' select="/Categories/cat[contains(text(),'Hybrid,Video']"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

It works if I just one value like below

```
<xsl:call-template name='xx'>
<xsl:with-param name='nodes' select="/Categories/cat[text()='Video']"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to filter 'Audio' and
>   pass the rest of nodes to a calling
>   template

Your second expression should be:

```
/Categories/cat[text()='Hybrid' or text()='Video']
```

But, I would use:

```
/Categories/cat[.!='Audio']
```

Or

```
/Categories/cat[not(.='Audio')]
```

Comment: /Categories/cat[text()='Hybrid' or text()='Video'] , expression is not working.  At the same time , I can't use /Categories/cat[.!='Audio'] because, I have more than one value which need to be suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked fine.

```
/Categories/cat[. ='Hybrid' or . ='Video']
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: `text()` is not different from `self::node()` string value in the provided imput sample. If this is so in real input, then you didn't provide a good example...